# Why the OnEndDrag event is not called?

Tags: delphi, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to detect the end of a drag & drop operation by using the [TControl.OnEndDrag event](http://docs.embarcadero.com/products/rad_studio/delphiAndcpp2009/HelpUpdate2/EN/html/delphivclwin32/Controls_TControl_OnEndDrag.html).

It seems that the `OnEndDrag` event is never called when the `DragObject` parameter is assigned from the `OnStartDrag` event.

```
  TMyForm = class(TForm)
    procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  public
    MyLabel : TLabel;
    procedure MyOnEndDrag(Sender, Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
    procedure MyOnStartDrag(Sender: TObject; var DragObject: TDragObject);
  end;

procedure TMyForm.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  MyLabel := TLabel.Create(Self);
  MyLabel.Caption := 'Drag me';
  MyLabel.Left := 50;
  MyLabel.Top := 50;
  MyLabel.OnStartDrag := MyOnStartDrag;
  MyLabel.OnEndDrag := MyOnEndDrag;
  MyLabel.DragMode := dmAutomatic;
  MyLabel.Parent := Self;
end;

procedure  TMyForm.MyOnEndDrag(Sender, Target: TObject; X, Y: Integer);
begin
  ShowMessage('MyOnEndDrag');
end;

procedure  TMyForm.MyOnStartDrag(Sender: TObject; var DragObject: TDragObject);
begin
  DragObject := TDragObjectEx.Create;
end;
```

I think the problem could be related to the DragObject's class but I don't understand what I'm doing wrong. How can I make sure the `OnEndDrag` event is called?

Comment: Need to use a DragControlObject[Ex] for that.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: Using TDragControlObjectEx have solved my problem, thank you

Comment: @SertacAkyuz: If you post it as an answer I'll accept it as solution to the question

Comment: Done. You're welcome.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A drag object needs to know which control it should notify when the drag ends. The specialized class for this kind of operation in the VCL, that is a drag object that can be associated with a single control, is a `TBaseDragControlObject`. `TDragControlObject[Ex]` is the appropriate descendant which deals with dropping as opposed to its sibling `TDragDockObject` which deals with docking.

```
DragObject := TDragControlObjectEx.Create(MyLabel);
```